# WPF DataGrid deleted rows don't get updated (deleted) in the database

Tags: sql, wpf, database, sql-update, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in my application, whose XML definition is as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          Visibility="{Binding gridVisibility}"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource ValidationReadyCellStyle}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ColumnWidth="*"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DBtable, ValidatesOnExceptions=False,
          NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, TargetNullValue={x:Static system:String.Empty}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="grid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" CanUserAddRows="True"
          BeginningEdit="grid_OnBeginningEdit" PreviewKeyDown="grid_OnPreviewKeyDown" RowEditEnding="grid_OnRowEditEnding" CellEditEnding="grid_OnCellEditEnding">
          <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
              <local:RowValidationChecker ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
          </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
</DataGrid>
```

As can be seen, the `ItemsSource` is bound to a table named `DBtable`, depending on which the rows/columns are automatically generated. Following is the code snippet used for connecting to and updating the database:

```
public bool SaveToDB(DataTable table, string tableName)
{
    var msSqlConnectionClass = new MsSqlConnectionClass(MsSqlLogin.Default.Server,
                                                            MsSqlLogin.Default.LoremIpsumDB, MsSqlLogin.Default.UID,
                                                            MsSqlLogin.Default.Password, MsSqlLogin.Default.WinAuth);
    SqlConnection msSqlConnection = msSqlConnectionClass.getMsSqlConnection();
    msSqlConnection.Open();
    try
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, msSqlConnection);
        SqlCommandBuilder command = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.UpdateCommand = command.GetUpdateCommand();
        da.DeleteCommand = command.GetDeleteCommand();
        da.InsertCommand = command.GetInsertCommand();
        da.Update(table);
        msSqlConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ServiceLog.AddLogInfo(e.ToString());
        msSqlConnection.Close();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is, although any addition or edit operation done in the `DataGrid` gets perfectly updated in the database, I am unfortunately unable to achieve the same behaviour for the deletion operation. The deletion is done in the source itself, so when I check the row count after a deletion operation (for which I use `DBtable.Rows.RemoveAt()`), `DBtable` shows me that the row is deleted, however the changes are not reflected in the database after the update attempt made using the `SaveToDB()` function shown above. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently

```
Dbtable.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
```

does not let the data table know that a deletion command has been issued. Hence, when an update command is run over the database, no deletion is seen and executed. Instead, using

```
row = DBtable.Rows[selectedIndex];
row.Delete();
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar confused me as well. Here is a solution for those who may encounter this page while searching later.

```
public DataTable GetMembers()
        {
            conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = DataModel.sdf");
            dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select * from Members", conn);
            commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            dataTable.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_RowChanged);
            dataTable.RowDeleted += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dataTable_RowDeleted);
            dataTable.DefaultView.ListChanged += DefaultView_ListChanged;
            return dataTable;
        }

        void DefaultView_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ListChangedType == System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```